# Angular Lazy loading strategy

Tags: angular

I have a angular 6 project working on with about 15 pages and i want implement angular lazy loading, through my research i got bit confused .

My questions is do i  have to create module file for each component or just one module file for all the component im applying the lazy loading and  with in an easy step !!
Any help here

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image

Comment: @aduguid probably i don't need to, this a kinda big app and i can pour everything here after all  this routing part in the code posted the picture. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loaded module can have one or more components inside it. But the module which you are going to lazy load needs to be a different module then your root module

So in your case if you want to lazy load every single component for each route you have to create a module file for each component

For example if you are trying to lazyload your dashboard component on route Dashboard then you have to create a 
Dashboard module with all the components it need

You can have a look here for more info 
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Let me know if this answers your question